# CSS :hover doesn't work with IE in SharePoint

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

```css
.element {
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}
.element:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(35, 173, 278, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="element" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

This code works perfectly in Chrome and IE 11, BUT when I use this code in SharePoint, the IE does not detect the hover-event. Chrome does. Only when the div has a background color, the IE detects the event.
Does anyone know why?!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201736/css-hover-in-sharepoint-works-in-chrome-but-not-ie8-or-7-compat

Comment: Yup. Sharepoint's CSS might be overriding yours considering your using IE>9. Check this SO for any possible answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379994/css-hover-codes-mysteriously-not-working-in-sharepoint-page

Comment: I'd actually be fine with using `!important` here.

Comment: I tried everything mentioned and nothing really works... even to jQuery method "hover()"  only works when the div has a background color. Why does it work with a background color defined?!

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

The **box-shadow**  property has support from IE9.
Please check for the CSS property browser support.

Comment: The IE 9 supports it and it works in a test html page I made, but it doesn't work in SharePoint...

Comment: There has an some restrictions for border-radius, box-shadow in share point . Try this I have referred from another site. They mentioned that we need to add this meta tag to specify the browser compatibility for sharepoint. <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >

Comment: I have not the problem, that the box-shadow doesn't work (that works fine), the problem I have is, that the IE ignores the hover-event if the div doesn't have a background... Everything works when I define a background color.

Answer (score -1):

Use css prefix [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411026/list-of-css-vendor-prefixes) for link which will help you. here is basic list.

- `-moz-` (Firefox)
- `-o-` (Opera)
- `-ms-` (Internet Explorer)
- `-webkit-` (Safari, Chrome)

also consider for use higher version of IE for future development very less people use it nowadays if you have any new difficulty in new version you do not have to think about too much for it , its Microsoft fault they doing things way different than Open Source world.

Comment: and isn't IE 11 the latest version?

Comment: than as i said you can loose it, and go for next thing if its does not have standard solution than its does not need to be worry about, by doing this you will save so much time and effort in your carrier. use another browser and recommended people to use another browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to work on IE... but I think you're right... I should look for another solution.